# Segfault when calling GetBinaryTypeA

Tags: winapi, rust, ffi

I tried to import the [`GetBinaryTypeA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364819(v=vs.85).aspx) function:

```
use std::ffi::CString;

use ::std::os::raw::{c_char, c_ulong};
extern { fn GetBinaryTypeA(s: *const c_char, out: *mut c_ulong) -> i32; }

fn main() {
    let path = "absolute/path/to/bin.exe";

    let cpath = CString::new(path).unwrap();
    let mut out: c_ulong = 0;

    println!("{:?}", cpath);
    unsafe { GetBinaryTypeA(cpath.as_ptr(), out as *mut c_ulong); }
    println!("{:?}", cpath);
}
```

Output:

```
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\bin_deploy.exe` (exit code: 3221225477)
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

If I set an invalid path then it executes successfully and `GetLastError()` returns 2 ("The system cannot find the file specified"), so it looks like the imported function works.

I received the same error using the kernel32-sys crate. Where else can the error be?

Comment: There is no *"segfault"* in Windows. Please exercise more diligence in representing your problem.

Comment: @IInspectable Why do not you edit the question to correct that?

Comment: @Boiethios: I cannot reproduce the issue, and I don't know the exact error message. `0xC0000005` looks like an access violation, but I have no idea, how the Rust runtime reports this. Since you can presumably reproduce the issue on your machine, why not propose an edit yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are casting the value `0` to a pointer. On the vast majority of computers in use today, the pointer with the value `0` is known as `NULL`. Thus, you are trying to write to the `NULL` pointer, which causes a crash.

You want to write to the address of the value:

```
&mut out as *mut c_ulong
```

Which doesn't even need the cast:

```
unsafe {
    GetBinaryTypeA(cpath.as_ptr(), &mut out);
}
```

Comment: More information about rust pointers: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html